# Why rotation happens just one time?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

How can I rotate my view on each button click?

When I try to:

```
@IBAction func replaceCurrencies(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(0.5), animations: {
        self.arrows.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
}
```

it rotates just one time. It do not rotate for the next my clicks. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you push your button again your view already have this transform. You need to reset it to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` or rotate from current transform. Second way is preferable because it will not jump to start before rotating:

```
@IBAction func replaceCurrencies(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.arrows.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.arrows.transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
    })
}
```

Comment: please include the closing `)` which OP missed in his code after the first closing `}`

Comment: @luk2302, you're right, I miss it when copy-paste. Thanks

Comment: no problem - you solved the actual problem, therefore the minor typo is not really an issue.